# Limit calculus for an addition

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}  $$

How can this be solved? I knot that I have to transform it in a subtracting sequence, but how?

Comment: Use MathJax please, otherwise your question is very hard to read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{1/2}{2k-1}-\frac{1/2}{2k+1}$ and telescope.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we evaluate the sum, and then we will take the limit.

If you use partial fractions, you get a telescoping series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl({1\over 2(2k-1)}-{1\over 2(2k+1)}\Bigr)=\frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl({1\over 2k-1}-{1\over 2k+1}\Bigr)={1\over 2}\Bigl(\Bigl(1-{1\over 3}\Bigr)+\Bigl({1\over 3}-{1\over 5}\Bigr)+\cdots +\Bigl({1\over 2n-1}-{1\over 2n+1}\Bigr)\Bigr)\\={1\over 2}\Bigl(1-{1\over 2n+1}\Bigr)=\color{blue}{n\over 2n+1}$$

Then if we take the limit as $n$ approaches to $\infty$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}{n\over 2n+1}=\color{red}{\frac 12}$$